# Error When Inserting Formula greater than 255 characters

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

I have previously used this method within my program to insert a formula which was a lot larger however I am receiving "run-time error code 1004 unable to set the FormulaArray property of the range class" with this one:

```
Sub TEST()
Dim QFormula As String
Dim QCountF As String
Dim QCountF2 As String
Dim WStart As String
Dim MoreDash As String
Dim ValueF As String

    QFormula = "=IF($K3=4,IF(_Q_>0,1,_M_),IF($K3=2,IF(_Q_>0,1,IF(COLUMN(P3)-MATCH(_S_,$A$1:P$1,0)>=8,IF(_Q2_>0,1,_M_),_M_)),IF(_Q_>0,1,IFERROR(IF((COLUMN(P3)-MATCH(_S_,$A$1:P$1,0)+1)-_V_<=13,1,_M_),_M_))))"

    QCountF = "COUNTA(OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(P3),COLUMN(P3)-4)),0,1,1,3))"
    QCountF2 = "COUNTA(OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(P3),COLUMN(P3)-8)),0,1,1,3))"
    WStart = """START"""
    MoreDash = """-"""
    ValueF = "VALUE(MATCH(1,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(P3),MATCH(_S_,$A$1:P$1,0))):O3,0))"

With ActiveCell
    .FormulaArray = QFormula
    .Replace "_Q_", QCountF
    .Replace "_Q2_", QCountF2
    .Replace "_S_", WStart
    .Replace "_M_", MoreDash
    .Replace "_V_", ValueF

  End With

  End Sub
```

I am at a loss as to where I have gone wrong this time and am hoping you can help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken straight from [msdn site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837104.aspx):

If you use this property to enter an array formula, the formula must use the R1C1 reference style, not the A1 reference style (see the example).

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E1:E3").FormulaArray = "=Sum(R1C1:R3C3)"
```

**Update edit:**

As you stated in comments even though msdn states you have to use `R1C1` reference the `A1` reference works too.

The actual issue in your code is:

```
ValueF = "VALUE(MATCH(1,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(P3),MATCH(_S_,$A$1:P$1,0))):O3,0))"
```

you have another `_S_` within the replacement code this never gets changed as its already past the `_S_` `.Replace`.

Fix:

```
ValueF = "VALUE(MATCH(1,INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(P3),MATCH(""START"",$A$1:P$1,0))):O3,0))"
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I have however done this successfully with a different, longer formula, earlier in the program in the A1 reference style. I had read elsewhere on this forum that there can be an issue if the formula doesn't follow the correct syntax when abbreviated. I don't know whether this could be the issue?

Comment: @Mac I didn't bother checking if what you did worked, my bad. I ran your code and it worked but then I found the actual error will update my answer.

Comment: Samu thank you for your help, I don't know how long that would of taken me to notice!!